# xdpoffload attach failed: Invalid argument

Tags: go, ebpf, xdp-bpf

When I try to attach a BPF program in XDP offload mode, I get `Invalid argument`. I get the same error if attach through code or by using `bpftool`. Here's how I'm attaching using [netlink](https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink):

```
err = netlink.LinkSetXdpFdWithFlags(link, objects.CollectIpsProg.FD(), 8)
```

And from using `bpftool`:

```
# bpftool prog loadall collect_ips.o /sys/fs/bpf/collect_ips type xdp
# bpftool net attach xdpoffload id 106 dev public
Error: interface xdpoffload attach failed: Invalid argument
```

I don't have any issues loading the program in driver mode, where `4` is passed to `LinkSetXdpFdWithFlags`.

My NIC, Mellanox MT28800 Family [ConnectX-5 Ex], should support HW offload.

My main XDP program makes calls to two different tail programs. I use `BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PROG_ARRAY, and BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mellanox cards support some hardware offload (e.g., flow control rules), but not the offload of BPF programs as far as I know. The only Ethernet adapters out there that support BPF offloading are [Netronome's cards](https://www.netronome.com/blog/ever-deeper-bpf-update-hardware-offload-support/).

---

One way to check this is to grep for the `XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW` BPF netdev command in the Linux source code:

```
$ git grep XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW
drivers/net/ethernet/netronome/nfp/nfp_net_common.c:    case XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW:
drivers/net/netdevsim/bpf.c:    if (bpf->command == XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW && !ns->bpf_xdpoffload_accept) {
drivers/net/netdevsim/bpf.c:    if (bpf->command == XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW) {
drivers/net/netdevsim/bpf.c:    case XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW:
include/linux/netdevice.h:      XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW,
net/core/dev.c: xdp.command = mode == XDP_MODE_HW ? XDP_SETUP_PROG_HW : XDP_SETUP_PROG;
```

That command is used to tell the driver to offload the BPF program to the hardware, via the `ndo_bpf` callback function.

Comment: I thought it was one of these [values](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/include/uapi/linux/if_link.h#L1180). This means that netlink doesn't support HW offload?

Comment: Assuming 8 is the value for HW offload, I don't see any code in ```LinkSetXdpFdWithFlags``` or the functions it calls that would prevent it from using 8.

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right. And the problem is elsewhere; I had missed the network card you're using. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also added a way to check that in the source in case it ever changes. Note the netdevsim here is a driver for testing purposes only.

Comment: Is it the case the HW doesn't support offload or just the driver?

Comment: Probably the hardware, but maybe Mellanox has some NPU in some of their cards that could execute BPF programs with a bit of work. Note that in the case of Netronome a special JIT compiler is also needed to convert the BPF bytecode in a format that the card understands (including 32-bit registers).

Comment: Ok. What are the limitations of offloaded programs? For example, would user space get notifications on a ring buffer write.

Comment: From what I have found online, offloading is sort of limited, the full explanation doesn't fit in a comment. Here are some good links:
- https://www.netronome.com/documents/305/eBPF-Getting_Started_Guide.pdf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WXsTixR4ak
- https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/xdp/attachments/slides/2220/export/events/attachments/xdp/slides/2220/fosdem18_SdN_NFV_qmonnet_XDPoffload.pdf
- https://www.netronome.com/documents/141/viljoen-xdpoffload-talk.pdf

Comment: Do you know if tail calls and support for all maps is still "future work?" Those documents are old. I assume driver is the most commonly used mode.

Comment: I haven't seen work from Netronome in the kernel in a long while, so they may indeed still be "future work".